# I have answered one question but now I'm banned from answering. Can I please have the ban lifted?

Tags: support, post-ban

The answer that I gave received one up vote, so I can't understand that it is unhelpful - if it was down voted or ignored then maybe.  How can I now get unbanned - I have only one answer which I must apparently improve, but I can't really make it that much better?

Comment: Maybe you should stop promoting your product and start actually participating productively in the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have three deleted answers. All your answers posted promote one product without disclosure. This is considered as spam and abusive – under normal circumstances your account would have been placed in a timed suspension or deleted altogether.

See [our help page](https://superuser.com/help/behavior):

> **Avoid overt self-promotion.**
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

I don't see a way for you to correct this other than trying to participate by asking good questions, proposing edits on posts, et cetera. There might be a way to get unbanned, but given that the specifics of the banning algorithm aren't known, it might not work.

If you want to promote XpressDox, you can buy ad space on Super User by [contacting the Stack Exchange sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact).

Comment: The more I think of this the more embarrassed I feel.  It's true - I do want to promote my product, but I did honestly believe that it would help in the situations where I posted answers.  I understand that my lack of disclosure could be construed as trying to mislead, but that really was not my intention - at worst I thought my full disclosure in my profile would be enough.  I want to offer my apologies to the community - I am a great fan of Stack Exchange and there is no way that I want to undermine it by undesired activity.

Comment: @Peter It would be very helpful if you could hang around and provide answers to questions that people ask **about XpressDox itself** on the SE network. Recommending XpressDox when the OP didn't specifically ask for it, however, is more iffy -- especially if you don't disclose *in your answer* that you wrote it, and at least provide some honest and good-faith comparison between your product and some other (perhaps even recommending another product if yours doesn't fit the bill in the user's specific situation).